# Overhead in using "Verify-full" while connecting postgresql through SSL

Tags: java, postgresql, ssl, ssl-certificate

Am trying to establish a secure connection using SSL for postgres RDS instance. I wanted to use SSL MODE "verify-full",since it provides the highest protection while transferring sensitive data.

As mentioned in the doc [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/libpq-ssl.html), I see that using "verify-full" provides some overhead in performance. I tried searching multiple sites but was unable to find the overhead stats. Has anyone tried it can kindly help.

1. How fast is encryption and decryption of records?
2. Is it advisable to use when dealing with 10K+ records and what will be the performance rate drop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not `sslmode=verify-full` that incurs a performance penalty, it is using encrypted connections as such.

It is impossible to give you a simple percentage by which you can performance to drop. The additional load is on the CPU, so if your workload is I/O bound or network bound, you may experience no performance drop at all.

You should set up a little test case and perform some benchmarks, that is the only way to get reliable data.